# Kafka Create Topic API Options for Non-Java Languages

Tags: apache-kafka

While you can create a topic via Java or Java-based languages (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225263/kafka-0-8-is-it-possible-to-create-topic-with-partition-and-replication-using-j)), there does not seem to be a clean way to do this without using Java. As a result, pure-language client APIs (like `kafka-node`, a pure JavaScript client) can't directly create topics. Instead, we have two options:

1) Use a hack like sending a metadata request to a topic -- if `auto.create.topics.enable` is set to `true`, then you can create a topic -- but only with the default configuration, no control over partitions, etc.

2) Write a wrapper around a Java-based client just for topic creation. The easiest way to do this is to `exec` the script `bin/kafka-topics.sh` with command line arguments, which is ugly, to say the least.

Is there a better way to do this, though? There's a pure-JavaScript client for Zookeeper, `node-zookeeper-client`, what happens if I manipulate broker / partition info directly in Zookeeper?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: There is another client, but with the same limitations for now http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/kafka-rest/docs/index.html

Comment: There is work being done in the Apache Kafka project on [KIP-4: Command line and centralized administrative operations](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-4+-+Command+line+and+centralized+administrative+operations) which will expose certain admin functions such as creating topics.  Once KIP-4 is finished you should soon see better options for non-Java languages.

As said by nautilus, Confluent's Kafka REST Proxy -- which is a popular tool for non-Java languages to interact with Kafka -- does not yet support creating Kafka topics;  KIP-4 may help here, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use REST Proxy API v3 to create Kafka topics with http requests for non-Java languages.

According to the [Confluent REST Proxy API Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#crest-long-api-reference) the creation of a topic is possible with the REST Proxy API v3 that is currently available as a preview feature.

> "The API v3 can be used for evaluation and non-production testing purposes or to provide feedback to Confluent."

An example of a **topic creation request** is presented below and documented [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--v3-clusters-(string-cluster_id)-topics):

```sh
POST /v3/clusters/cluster-1/topics HTTP/1.1
Host: kafkaproxy.example.com
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "topic_name": "topic-1",
      "partitions_count": 2,
      "replication_factor": 3,
      "configs": [
        {
          "name": "cleanup.policy",
          "value": "compact"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using `curl`:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
          --data '{"data":{"attributes": {"topic_name": "topic-1", "partitions_count": 2, "replication_factor": 1, "configs": [{"name": "cleanup.policy","value": "compact"}]}}}' \
          "http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/<cluster-id>/topics"
```

where the **`cluster-id`** can be identified using

```sh
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" localhost:8082/v3/clusters
```

Comment: It is no longer a preview feature, and the new link to topic creation is https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--clusters-cluster_id-topics