# Is it possible to create a topic with Kafka Rest Proxy?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to create a topic from Kafka Rest Proxy but I don't see any documentation for it.  I'm hoping there is a way to do it so I don't need to programmatically create a topic differently than I do all other communication.  Does anyone know if it possible?

I don't see any documentation for it here: http://docs.confluent.io/1.0/kafka-rest/docs/api.html.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The problem is there's no protocol support for creating topics (not yet, at least). See my previous question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957853/kafka-create-topic-api-options-for-non-java-languages)**, and read the comments.

Answer (score 13):

**With the version 3 of the REST Proxy API it is now possible.**

According to the [Confluent REST Proxy API Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#crest-long-api-reference) the creation of a topic is possible with the REST Proxy API v3 that is currently available as a preview feature.

An example of a **topic creation request** is presented below and documented [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--v3-clusters-(string-cluster_id)-topics):

```sh
POST /v3/clusters/cluster-1/topics HTTP/1.1
Host: kafkaproxy.example.com
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "topic_name": "topic-1",
      "partitions_count": 2,
      "replication_factor": 3,
      "configs": [
        {
          "name": "cleanup.policy",
          "value": "compact"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Using `curl`:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
          --data '{"data":{"attributes": {"topic_name": "topic-1", "partitions_count": 2, "replication_factor": 1, "configs": [{"name": "cleanup.policy","value": "compact"}]}}}' \
          "http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/<cluster-id>/topics"
```

where the **`cluster-id`** can be identified using

```sh
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" localhost:8082/v3/clusters
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with the latest version. See here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/rest-proxy.html#basic-producer-and-consumer

From the docs:

```
KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID=$(docker-compose exec rest-proxy curl -X GET \
     "http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/" | jq -r ".data[0].cluster_id")
```

Verify the parameter KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID has a valid value. For the example in this tutorial, it is shown as lkc-56ngz, but it will differ in your output.

```
echo $KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID
Create the Kafka topic test1 using the AdminClient functionality of the REST Proxy API v3.
```

```
docker-compose exec rest-proxy curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"topic_name\":\"test1\",\"partitions_count\":6,\"configs\":[]}" \
     "http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/${KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID}/topics" | jq .
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit admin API to create a topic in REST proxy yet, but if the Kafka broker property **auto.crate.topics.enable** is set to true the topic is created when you first post to it, including  the case when the post comes from the proxy. More info here [How to create topics in apache kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441768/how-to-create-topics-in-apache-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a topic with Azure HdInsight Kafka REST proxy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight-kafka-rest-proxy/admin

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/rest-proxy