# How to create topic with partitions in confluent kafka using curl

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I have a curl command given like this i'm trying to do a curl to create a topic on confluent kafka i have an issue understanding this curl statement, on official documentation curl command is given as below

```sh
$ curl "http://localhost:8082/topics/test"
  {"name":"test","num_partitions":3}
```

https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html#inspect-topic-metadata
Do i have to consider  {"name":"test","num_partitions":3} as data or is it a part of curl command..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a topic with Kafka Rest Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764243/is-it-possible-to-create-a-topic-with-kafka-rest-proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using v2.0 of the docs, I'd recommend the [latest (currently 5.5)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-05&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

To create a topic you can use the new API that was added in 5.5:

```
curl -s -X POST 'http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/rgfnzs2RS3O65A7VSpNatg/topics' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' \
--data-raw '{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "topic_name": "rmoff_topic03",
      "partitions_count": 1,
      "replication_factor": 1
    }
  }
}'
```

You need to get your cluster ID (`rgfnzs2RS3O65A7VSpNatg` in the example above), which you can do with

```
➜ curl -s -X GET 'localhost:8082/v3/clusters'| jq '.data[0].attributes.cluster_id'
"rgfnzs2RS3O65A7VSpNatg"
```

Ref: [v3 API docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#crest-api-v3?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-05&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

---

To delete a topic use the [corresponding API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#delete--v3-clusters-(string-cluster_id)-topics-(string-topic_name)):

```
curl -s -X DELETE 'http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/rgfnzs2RS3O65A7VSpNatg/topics/rmoff_topic03'
```

Comment: Thanks Robin..How to delete the topic..?

Comment: Using Rest proxy API is it possible to delete the new topic created...?