# how to create kafka topic using confluent rest api

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

Endpoint : http://localhost:8082/v3/clusters/cluster-id/topics

post body : {
"topic_name": "topic-X",
"partitions_count": 1,
"replication_factor": 1,
"configs": [
{
"name": "cleanup.policy",
"value": "compact"
},
{
"name": "compression.type",
"value": "gzip"
}
]
}

Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.confluent.kafkarest.entities.v3.CreateTopicRequest.getTopicName()" because "request" is null
at io.confluent.kafkarest.resources.v3.TopicsResource.createTopic(TopicsResource.java:137)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a topic with Kafka Rest Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764243/is-it-possible-to-create-a-topic-with-kafka-rest-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

able to create the topic after changing the port from 8082 to 8090
Endpoint : http://localhost:8090/v3/clusters/cluster-id/topics.

couple of things.
as per confluent documentation default listener is 8082, not sure of the 8090 port configuration

listeners

Type: list
Default: http://0.0.0.0:8082
Importance: high

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/production-deployment/rest-proxy/config.html

Comment: If port 8082 was not correct, you wouldn't have gotten any response at all