# "Could not find matching constructor" error while creating zookeeper client using kafka adminutils

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

```
 def index() {

        def sessionTimeoutMs = 10000
        def connectionTimeoutMs = 10000
        def zkClient = new ZkClient("127.0.0.1:2181", sessionTimeoutMs, connectionTimeoutMs, ZKStringSerializer )

        def topicName = "myTopicoo"
        def numPartitions = 8
        def replicationFactor = 3
        def topicConfig = new Properties()
        AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, topicName, numPartitions, replicationFactor, topicConfig)

        Properties propy=new Properties()
        propy.put("metadata.broker.list","localhost:9092")
        propy.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
        //propy.put("partitioner.class", "coughka.SimplePartitioner")
        propy.put("request.required.acks","1")

        ProducerConfig configuration=new ProducerConfig(propy)

        Producer<String,String> prod = new Producer<String,String>(configuration)
        def i=0
        while(i<90){
            prod.send(new KeyedMessage<String, String>("myTopicoo" , "nithin"+i.toString()))
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

> error: Could not find matching constructor for:
>   org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Class)

I followed this:
[How Can we create a topic in Kafka from the IDE using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946778/how-can-we-create-a-topic-in-kafka-from-the-ide-using-api/)

Comment: Which zookeeper version?

Comment: I found I am using zkclient 0.3 but the example I referred used zkclient 0.4 . Could you help me how to achieve the above using zkclient 0.3