# Error creating Kafka topic :- replication factor larger than available brokers

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a kafka topic via     AdminCommand     using below code [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23360100/1069073)

```
 ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(kafkaHost, 10000, 10000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
    AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, "pa_reliancepoc_telecom_usageevent", 10, 2, new Properties());
```

But getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:70)
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:155)
```

However, I am able to create the topic using shell command .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your code,

```
 AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, "pa_reliancepoc_telecom_usageevent", 10, 2, new Properties());
```

The fourth argument is the replication factor. So you are trying to create a topic with a name of `pa_reliancepoc_telecom_usageevent` with partition `count of 10` and `replication of 2`. So `two kafka brokers` should be available while creating the topic. If less than two is available then you will get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:70)
at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:155)
```

Make sure that you are running `kafka cluster with two broker nodes` and the two nodes `should be alive while creating the topic.`

To run kafka in cluster refer Step 6 in [this link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html)

Comment: In any case, the exception is grossly misleading and probably should read: "[...] replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1 "

Answer (score 5):

configure your local machine to have multiple brokers up and running in case you decide to keep your `replication_factor > 1`.

You can do that by simply having multiple copies of the 
`server.properties` file. e.g 
`server-1.properties` & `server-2.properties`

You need to then specify different `broker.id` & `port` in each of those files to make them unique ..

```
   config/server-1.properties:
     broker.id=1
     port=9093
     log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1

   config/server-2.properties:
     broker.id=2
     port=9094
     log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

And then start multiple instances with following commands

```
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties &
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-2.properties &
```

For more details check [Step 6: Setting up a multi-broker cluster](http://kafka.apache.org/081/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while setting up multiple brokers.

The step I was missing was:

While editing the config file:
    config/server-1.properties:
        broker.id=1
        listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
        log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1

need to update the LOG BASICS section as well(see below):

####################### Log Basics

## A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files

```
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```