# Exception when creating kafka topic through java

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a kafka topic via     AdminCommand     using below code [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23360100/1069073)

```
 ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(kafkaHost, 10000, 10000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
    AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, "pa_reliancepoc_telecom_usageevent", 10, 1, new Properties());
```

But getting the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkNoNodeException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkException.create(ZkException.java:47)
at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.retryUntilConnected(ZkClient.java:685)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your exception, It says it `could not able to connect zookeeper`.
In your code,

```
ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(kafkaHost, 10000, 10000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
```

The first argument is the `zookeeper host`, I don't know what you are having in the kafkaHost variable, As the name implies I think you have stored kafka host in that variable. Change the first argument by giving the `zookeeper host`. For example,

```
String zkHosts = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx:2181";
ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(zkHosts, 10000, 10000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
```

If you are having more then one zookeeper then give as comma separated string. For example,

`String zkHosts = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx:2181,yyy.yyy.yy.yy:2181";`