# How can you create a partition on a Kafka topic using Samza?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, partitioning, apache-samza

I have a few Samza jobs running all reading messages off of a Kafka topic and writing a new message to a new topic. To send the new messages, I am using Samza's built in OutgoingMessageEnvelope. Also using a MessageCollector to send out the new message. It looks something like this:

```
collector.send(new OutgoingMessageEnvelope(SystemStream, newMessage))
```

Is there a way I can use this to add partitions to the Kafka topic? Such as partitioning on a user ID or something like that.

Or if there is a better way I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to send messages using a [partitioning key](https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.9/api/javadocs/org/apache/samza/system/OutgoingMessageEnvelope.html#OutgoingMessageEnvelope-org.apache.samza.system.SystemStream-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-),

```
    public OutgoingMessageEnvelope(SystemStream systemStream,
                               java.lang.Object partitionKey,
                               java.lang.Object key,
                               java.lang.Object message)
Constructs a new OutgoingMessageEnvelope from specified components.
Parameters:
systemStream - Object representing the appropriate stream of which this envelope will be sent on.
partitionKey - A key representing which partition of the systemStream to send this envelope on.
key - A deserialized key to be used for the message.
message - A deserialized message to be sent in this envelope.
```

Using this method will partition your data. However I think if you are looking at controlling the number of partitions programmatically, you should use the kafka API to create/alter the topic as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946778/how-can-we-create-a-topic-in-kafka-from-the-ide-using-api/23360100#23360100)

Comment: I saw this in the docs as well but wasn't sure whether any serialization/deserialization configuration - similar to key and message - is needed or not for the partitionKey.

Comment: Did you find out whether any config was necessary?  Will Samza create all the necessary partitions for you by just using a different partitioning key?  Does it matter what object is passed as a partitioning key?