# Create a Kafka brokers cluster using Apache Kafka 0.10.0 API with Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I want to create a broker cluster using `Kafka 0.10 API` preferable with `Java`. As far as I have read `kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0.jar` do support creating broker using :

```
import kafka.cluster.Broker;
import kafka.cluster.Cluster;
```

But I can't find any documentation for doing so. I recently read [1], which tell how to create a topic using `Kafka API` in `Java`. Can we do similar things to  *create broker cluster, update partition, migrate existing data/partition to new broker* (as these new broker will not automatically be assigned any data partitions, so unless partitions are moved to them they won't be doing any work [2])

[1] [How Can we create a topic in Kafka from the IDE using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946778/how-can-we-create-a-topic-in-kafka-from-the-ide-using-api)

[2] https://kafka.apache.org/0100/ops.html#basic_ops_cluster_expansion

Answer (score -1):

I have some sample code which you may find useful.

For creating a broker, take a look at [KafkaTestServer](https://github.com/nickman/HeliosStreams/blob/master/stream-common/src/main/java/com/heliosapm/streams/kafka/KafkaTestServer.java). It's really for simpler testing, so it does not create a cluster, just a single broker, but it should not be difficult to extend.

Once I built in the ability to create/query/delete topics into the test server, I created a standalone admin client for doing the same against other servers, so if you are already creating a broker cluster, you should be able to use the code to maintain topics on it. Take a look at [KafkaAdminClient](https://github.com/nickman/HeliosStreams/blob/master/stream-common/src/main/java/com/heliosapm/streams/kafka/KafkaAdminClient.java).

The admin client is basically a pure java wrapper around the scala **kafka.admin.AdminUtils** class so it handles all the scala <--> java conversions under the covers.