# Why do we need to specify Serializer in Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I got this doubt from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946778/how-can-we-create-a-topic-in-kafka-from-the-ide-using-api).

When I am not using Kafka Streams, Why do I need to use Serializer while creating ZkClient?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka havily uses zookeeper for storing metadata (topics). For that library com.101tec::zkClient is used. According to source code [ZkClient](https://github.com/sgroschupf/zkclient/blob/master/src/main/java/org/I0Itec/zkclient/ZkClient.java) it requires ZkSerializer for serializing/deserializing data send/retreived from zookeeper. Kafka inside itself has implementation of ZkSerializer: ZKStringSerializer (defied in zkUtils).

However, for usual interaction with kafka (producing / consuming) you do not need to create ZkClient. It is required only for 'administrative' work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please read the top voted comment in the link I posted. If we don't specify Serializer while creating topic, it is not actually created by Kafka. What does it mean? It is what confused me.

Comment: @GopsAB i will assume that it is connected the way how your topic name is serialized and written in zookeeper. When you display the list of topics - it is just list of all nodes in zookeeper. While kafka can treat it as invalid topic name