# Getting Error while creating Kafka Topic via Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have tried creating the topic in Kafka via Java, as mentioned in answer to this question:
[How Can we create a topic in Kafka from the IDE using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946778/how-can-we-create-a-topic-in-kafka-from-the-ide-using-api)

I am getting the following exception:

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper: {"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1495085433520","endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092"],"host":"0.0.0.0","version":3,"port":9092}
        at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:125)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getBrokerInfo(ZkUtils.scala:799)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getAllBrokersInCluster$2.apply(ZkUtils.scala:253)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getAllBrokersInCluster$2.apply(ZkUtils.scala:253)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster(ZkUtils.scala:253)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.getBrokerMetadatas(AdminUtils.scala:393)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:415)
        at kafka.admin.AdminUtils.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala)
        at com.freecharge.payments.kafka.Test.main(Test.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$$anonfun$1.apply(EndPoint.scala:32)
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$$anonfun$1.apply(EndPoint.scala:32)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<init>(EndPoint.scala:32)
        at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<clinit>(EndPoint.scala)
        at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$2.apply(Broker.scala:115)
        at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$2.apply(Broker.scala:115)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:115)
```

I have stuck into this for around 3 days, please help.

Maven Configuration is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
    <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Show your Maven dependencies to check all of them are the same Scala version.

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>0.10.2.0</version>

<groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
<artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
<version>0.9</version>

<groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
<artifactId>common-config</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>

<groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
<artifactId>common-utils</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>

<groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>

<groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>

Comment: You could just update you answer with maven config.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely versions of Zookeeper client and Kafka are incompatible. Try to use version 0.10 of zkclient:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.101tec/zkclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
    <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.10</version>
</dependency>
```