# Choosing the right cleanup policy in Kafka configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1. I created the topics with 1 partitions. I know that the default cleanup policy is "delete". I want to keep all the records in the topic all the time (without deleting any record). What's the right way : make "log.cleaner.enable=false" or "log.cleanup.policy=compact"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Topics have broker-wide configs that apply by default to any topic that doesn't have a config, but topics can also have topic-specific configs that override or complement broker-wide topic configs.

Broker-wide topic configs are set in your `service.properties` file. Topic specific configs are set using the `bin/kafka-topics.sh` script or `AdminClient` if you are using Java.

The relevant broker-wide config for you is `log.retention.ms` and the equivalent topic-specific config is `retention.ms`. If you set `log.retention.ms` to `-1`, all topics without this the `retention.ms` config will have an infinite retention period. Likewise, if you set `-1` for `retention.ms` on a specific topic, it will have an infinite retention period.

To set `retention.ms` on a new topic:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --create --topic my_topic_name
  --partitions 20 --replication-factor 3 --config retention.ms=-1
```

You can also modify an existing topic to set `retention.ms` to `-1`:

```
> bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot --entity-type topics --entity-name my_topic_name --alter --add-config retention.ms=-1
```

See the full list of topic-specific configs here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs and more about topic operations: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops

Comment: Given this description: "This configuration controls the maximum time we will retain a log before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the "delete" retention policy. This represents an SLA on how soon consumers must read their data. If set to -1, no time limit is applied." I think compaction will still happen, even if this is set to -1 if the cleanup policy is "compact". I've just had this config on our setup and it compacted old logs.