# How to declaratively manage Kafka topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, infrastructure-as-code, configuration-as-code

We're using Apache Kafka and have a lot of manually created topics (with custom topic config). We want to manage our topics like the rest of our infrastructure/configuration as code.

How can we programmatically and declaratively manage our topics? Whats the sane way?

Comment: What is your definition of "manage"?

Comment: Terraform plugins exist for Kafka...

Comment: Personally, I have developed an open-source tool for doing that with a GitOps approach : https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-specs

Answer (score 7):

Here is a list of tools that might fit what you are looking for. They are all focused around declaratively managing resources, such as topics and ACLs, in Kafka.

#### Command-line

- [jikkou](https://github.com/streamthoughts/jikkou)
- [kafka-gitops](https://github.com/devshawn/kafka-gitops)
- [kdef](https://github.com/peter-evans/kdef)
- [topicctl](https://github.com/segmentio/topicctl)

#### Terraform

- [terraform-provider-kafka](https://github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka)