# How do you programmatically create a topic with Kafka 1.1.0

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I recently upgraded to Kafka 1.1.0. I am trying to create unit tests for the kafka consumer. For this purpose it would be ideal if the unit test can create the topic it uses for the test. I found some code that looks like it should do what I want. However, when I run it it throws an exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeQuietly(Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Here is the code to create a topic which I found on line:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void createTopic() {
   try (final AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(configure())) {
        try {
            // Define topic
            NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic("test-orders", 1, (short)1);

            // Create topic, which is async call.
            final CreateTopicsResult createTopicsResult = adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic));

            // Since the call is Async, Lets wait for it to complete.
            createTopicsResult.values().get(ordersTopic).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            if (!(e.getCause() instanceof TopicExistsException)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it throws an exception when I run it.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeQuietly(Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:334)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:52)
at com.sial.notifications.topics.OrdersTopicsTests.createTopic(OrdersTopicsTests.java:162)
```

The only configuration parameters I pass to it is the bootstrap servers and a client.id.
What am I doing wrong? it seems simple enough

Comment: You'll get that error when your classpath isn't setup correctly

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946778/how-can-we-create-a-topic-in-kafka-from-the-ide-using-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This slightly modified code worked for me when I ran it stand-alone against a 1.1.0 broker:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String ordersTopic = "test-orders";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");

    try (final AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props)) {
        try {
            // Define topic
            NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(ordersTopic, 1, (short)1);

            // Create topic, which is async call.
            final CreateTopicsResult createTopicsResult = adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic));

            // Since the call is Async, Lets wait for it to complete.
            createTopicsResult.values().get(ordersTopic).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            if (!(e.getCause() instanceof TopicExistsException))
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Since this is pretty similar to your code, and based on the error you're seeing, perhaps you haven't completely sorted out the dependencies to Kafka libraries? I used the Maven artifact `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:1.1.0`.

Comment: thank you. The problem was that I use Eclipse, and it was holding onto the older kafka version's jars in its build path. If I had run the unit tests from the command line this would have worked.

Comment: Following up with this comment, I too had recently upgraded from a Kafka-client that was in the 0.10 version to 1.0... version and was running into this error, the older version was still hanging around, once I removed it, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way is to just configure Kafka to automatically create any topic you use that does not exist already with the

`auto.create.topics.enable`

setting for Kafka. Doing this, there is *no* extra code needed for creating topics. You just use whatever topic name you want, and Kafka will create it for you when you use it.

Comment: It's not possible due to restrictions on some environments. You also can't define important config settings like partitions and replications.