# How to efficiently create Kafka topics with testcontainers?

Tags: apache-kafka, testcontainers

I am using testcontainers.org with `KafkaContainer`.

Currently, I use `kafka-topics` to create a topic after starting the container:

```
kafkaContainer.execInContainer("/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic topicName");
```

As this takes around 3-5 seconds per topic, I am wondering, if there is a more efficient way to create multiple topics.
Or is there a simple switch to autocreate topics on demand?

Answer (score 15):

For reference, using the AdminClient was the most efficient.

Here is an example:

```java
  private static void createTopics(String... topics) {
    var newTopics =
        Arrays.stream(topics)
            .map(topic -> new NewTopic(topic, 1, (short) 1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    try (var admin = AdminClient.create(Map.of(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, getKafkaBrokers()))) {
      admin.createTopics(newTopics);
    }
  }

  private static String getKafkaBrokers() {
    Integer mappedPort = kafkaContainer.getFirstMappedPort();
    return String.format("%s:%d", "localhost", mappedPort);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `wurstmeister/kafka` container with `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` environment variable
2. You could use a higher level Kafka client like [Spring-Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics) or Dropwizard-Kafka which offer topic creation.
3. Otherwise, [use `AdminClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803638/2308683) directly

It's recommended not to enable auto topic creation on the brokers because it then has a default partition count and replication factor

Comment: FYI Testcontainers uses Confluent's image for Kafka and also configured to auto-create topics.

Comment: @bsideup As mentioned, auto-create on the broker gives default settings defined by the broker. The wurstmeister container allows for setting individiual replication and partition counts per topic.