# access case object (scala) from java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

in my scala code i have the following

```
trait A
object A {
  case object AB extends A
  case object AC extends A
}
```

how can i access `AB` or `AC` from java code?
i expected it to work like `A.AB`, but that does not work.

i also saw this: [How do I "get" a Scala case object from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561415/how-do-i-get-a-scala-case-object-from-java)
however, somewhere else I read, that you should never use `$` stuff in java code.

all I want to do in Java is to check if an object is of type `AB` or `AC`.

how can this be done in this case?

Comment: solution: access it from java via `A.AB$.MODULE$`

Comment: Did you able to resolve it? I am also facing the exact same issue.

Comment: yes, as can be seen in my comment above, I used `A.AB$.MODULE$` in java. This worked.