# eclipse raises syntax error even though code compiles correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

i hava a project with scala and java code.

i access a scala class via `AB$.MODULE$` as can be seen in the solution/comment here: [access case object (scala) from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629382/access-case-object-scala-from-java?noredirect=1#comment47401652_29629382)

everything works fine, however, eclipse underlines `AB$.MODULE$` with red color saying that `AB$ cannot be resolved to a variable`. however, the code compiles correctly and works fine. so how can i avoid the error from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem fairly regularly. What works for me is cleaning the project in Eclipse. Just click on the project then Project->Clean.

If you are using Maven you can also try updating your Eclipse project with your Maven dependencies. Right click on project then Maven->Update project.

Hope this helps

Comment: good hint. unfortunately it did not help in my specific case. it seems to be some sort of java-scala-interoperability problem. eclipse seems not to be fully okay with the `AB$.MODULE$` accessor..