# Get case object from Scala Object

Tags: java, scala

How to access the `CALL_INDEX` object from java class:

**MyStrategy.scala**

```
trait CallStrategy 
object CallStrategy {
  case object CALL_INDEX extends CallStrategy 
}

trait MyStrategy { def random(as: CallStrategy) } 

object MyStrategy extends MyStrategy 
{
   def random(as: CallStrategy) = { //Some code }
}
```

In another scala file I can access the `CALL_INDEX` using:
`CallStrategy.CALL_INDEX`

But in java, I am not able to access it as follows:

**StrategyUser.java**

```
CallStrategy$ callStrategy = CallStrategy$.MODULE$;
MyStrategy$ myStrategy = MyStrategy$.MODULE$;
myStrategy.random(callStrategy); // compile time error
```

The above java code is giving compile time error:

`The method random(CallStrategy) in the type MyStrategy$ is not applicable for the arguments (CallStrategy$)`

I used the above java code by taking help from:

[How do I "get" a Scala case object from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561415/how-do-i-get-a-scala-case-object-from-java)

**UPDATE:**

Please see the image below for clarification:

[image]

Even I added two more statements in the code and still the same compile time error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like below:

```
MyStrategy$.MODULE$.random(CallStrategy.CALL_INDEX$.MODULE$);
```

In your code you are trying to access the CALL_INDEX from CallStrategy object, rather, it's available in CallStrategy interface.

Update 1: (Full Code)

**MyStrategy.scala:**

```
trait CallStrategy

object CallStrategy {
  case object CALL_INDEX extends CallStrategy
}

trait MyStrategy {
  def random(as: CallStrategy)
}

object MyStrategy extends MyStrategy {
  def random(as: CallStrategy) = {
    println(as)
  }
}
```

**StrategyUser.java:**

```
public class StrategyUser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStrategy$.MODULE$.random(CallStrategy.CALL_INDEX$.MODULE$);
    }
}
```

And FYI, I am using scala version '2.11.7' and java version '1.7.0_75'

Comment: It is not able to recongnize CALL_INDEX$ as a field or a variable. Can you please provide the scala libraries to use because it seems that some configuration is incorrect. My project is having two files: One scala file and one java file. Java file is calling method of scala file. See the images attached in question for a clearer view and project structure.

Comment: I can successfully as mentioned in the code above without any problems. I am using Intellij and the mentioned scala and java versions. It could be a problem with eclipse. Can you provide your eclipse version and the sbt plugin version?

Comment: oh yes you are right. My eclipse Mars is giving compile time error at `CALL_INDEX$` from your above code but when I run `StrategyUser.java`, I get the OUTPUT. That means the problem is only eclipse being not able to recognize `CALL_INDEX$` as a field or a variable of scala. My eclipse scala version is also `2.11.7` and java version `1.8.0_65`. Also my sbt version is `sbt 0.13.8`

Comment: Also can you point out some good online resources to grasp Scala as I am new to it. Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I found the following series of tutorials to be very useful: 1. [Neophyte's guide to scala](http://danielwestheide.com/scala/neophytes.html). And don't miss to checkout 2. [Martin's course in Coursera](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-003)

Answer (score 1):

```
CallStrategy callStrategy = CallStrategy$.MODULE$.CALL_INDEX$.MODULE$
```

Your current code doesn't mention `CALL_INDEX` at all: it's equivalent to `MyStrategy.random(CallStrategy)` in Scala.

Comment: Now talking about your statement: When I use `CallStrategy$.MODULE$.` and then press `Control + Space` then there is no drop down with `CALL_INDEX$`. Still I typed it. I wrote that complete statement and it is giving compile time error saying: `CALL_INDEX$ cannot be resolved or is not a field`. I am using `Eclipse IDE` which shows the methods to choose when we presses `Control + Space`.

Comment: `MyStrategy.scala` file is in the package: `com.test.user`. So I used the following import statement: import `com.test.user.CallStrategy$;`. I typed half statement `CallStrategy callStrategy = CallStrategy$.` and pressed the key `Control + Space` and the `CALL_INDEX$` was appearing in the drop down list. I chose it. Then again I pressed Control + Space. Now I got `MODULE$` from the drop down. I chose it. Complete statement now is: `CallStrategy callStrategy = CallStrategy$.CALL_INDEX$.MODULE$;`. Still compile time error: `cannot convert from CallStrategy$.CALL_INDEX$ to CallStrategy`.

Comment: I am not sure that despite of eclipse giving me the list to choose from when I press `Control + Space`, I got the compile time errors when I write these statements. However, I am not getting any error when I use: `CallStrategy$ callStrategy= CallStrategy$.MODULE$;`.

Comment: You need to get a `CallStrategy`, not a `CallStrategy$`. Are you sure you are getting the error in your previous comment with `CallStrategy callStrategy = CallStrategy$.CALL_INDEX$.MODULE$;`? This error message would make more sense if you had `CallStrategy callStrategy = CallStrategy$.CALL_INDEX$;`.

Comment: `CallStrategy` is the type of `trait CallStrategy`; `CallStrategy$` is the type of `object CallStrategy`. So, as said above, it makes no sense to call `MyStrategy.random` with the object as its argument.

Comment: Understood. But the problem is - I want to call the following method which is in scala file: `def random(as: CallStrategy)` as you see in my question. So the argument that it takes is of type of `trait CallStrategy`. Right? So in java class I have to call like that. Right? My problem is really same as this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629382/access-case-object-scala-from-java?rq=1

Comment: As mentioned, please recheck `CallStrategy callStrategy = CallStrategy$.CALL_INDEX$.MODULE$;`. The error message doesn't make sense because this code doesn't try to `convert from CallStrategy$.CALL_INDEX$ to CallStrategy` at all.